# Fetching second maximum date json object(postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch second max date json data from an json column..

Here is jsonb column

```
--------
 value
--------
{
    "id": "90909",
    "records": [
        {
            "name":"john",
            "date": "2016-06-16"
        },
        {
             "name":"kiran",
            "date": "2017-06-16"
        },
        {
            "name":"koiy",
            "date": "2018-06-16"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to select the second maximum date json object in the jsonb column..

expected output:-

```
 {
     "name":"kiran",
     "date": "2017-06-16"
 }
```

and if we have only one object inside the records means that will be the second max date

and any suggestions would also helpful..

Comment: The key is `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`.The rest of the query is complicated, because you mistakenly decided to store these perfectly tabular data in a denormalized fashion. Avoiding JSON in the database is the way to go in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way of doing it could be, get all the dates in an array, then sort the array in DESC and then get the second date. all these steps can be done in a single query

Comment: Can you please provide some basic query for that?